# Inserir sem explicitar as colunas

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

Tenho várias tabelas T1,T2... TN, cada uma pode ter colunas em comum ou não.
A minha tabela final F, contém todas as colunas (um única vez) das anteriores.

Tem como eu inserir de cada uma sem ter que explicitar quais colunas estou inserindo?

Por exemplo, digamos que a tabela T1 tem as colunas A e B. Na tabela F tem A,B,C e D.

Gostaria de algo do tipo

```
insert into F select * FROM T1;
```

ou

```
insert into F select A,B,C,D FROM T1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não. Não é possível fazer INSERT sem definir as colunas. 
Quando você usa

```
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES(a, b, c)
```

você está implicitamente dizendo que vai usar TODAS as colunas na ordem em que elas foram criadas.

Mas é possível usar isso para fazer coisas como:

```
INSERT INTO a SELECT a, null, 'X' FROM  b WHERE condicao
```

desde que suas colunas aceitem valor NULL e que um valor passado como padrão para cada linha possa aceitar 'X' como valor.

Um exemplo mais pratico para entender: Supondo B = (id_A, tp_Sangue, fator_RH) e A = (id_A, NOME, SEXO)

```
INSERT INTO B SELECT id_A, 'AB', 'RH+' FROM A WHERE SEXO='F';
```

Estaremos atribuindo 'AB' e 'RH+' a todos os registros com SEXO = 'F';

Uma outra forma de fazer algo como explicou sobre o `INSERT INTO F SELECT * FROM T1;` seria criar um VIEW contendo os campos iguais a F a partir de T1;

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Achei que assim como existe o JOIN natural, pudesse existir um "INSERT natural", inserindo as colunas de acordo com os nomes delas.

Comment: O MYSQL suport um tipo diferente de INSERT que usa a SINTAXE `INSERT INTO tabela SET campo1 = {expressao}, campo2 ={expressao}...`